# RxJava block stream until other observer completes

Tags: rx-java

I have a long running process in background that is processing files and posts it's progress to `BehaviorSubject` with `subject.onNext(progress)` and calls `subject.onCompleted` once it finishes.

At some point in flow I want to subscribe to that `subject` and get current progress or wait until it completes.

```
prepareOtherStuff()
    .flatMap(validate())
    .????? <- want to subscribe here
    .map(finalize())
    .subscribe()
```

I'm having trouble with `?????` part. Can't figure out how to block stream and wait until file processing is completed AND get file processing progress to display it to user.

For example:

```
-- other files already processed, don't care about them --
File 8 of 10 processed
File 9 of 10 processed
-- onCompleted received --
```

How can I achieve such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.concatWith` (where `TheType` is the generic type of the Observable returned from `.flatMap(validate())`):

```
prepareOtherStuff()
  .flatMap(validate())
  .concatWith(subject
             .doOnNext(m -> log.info(m))
             .ignoreElements()
             .cast(TheType.class))
  .map(finalize())
  .subscribe()
```